# What are the advantages of using runtime specific implementations?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

When running a `dotnet restore --runtime linux-musl-x64` from inside an alpine container, I noticed some `runtime.unix.System*` packages being downloaded, which are not downloaded when the `--runtime` flag is not specified. I'm assuming that is because when the `runtime` is not present dotnet restore defaults it to `any` restoring platform-agnostic implementations provided by the package. Is this a correct assumption?

I would like to know if it is documented anywhere the advantages of using runtime specific implementations of .Net CORE packages ? For instance `System.Net.Sockets` and `runtime.unix.System.Net.Sockets`. I would assume because they are not generic implementations they are more efficient from a memory and CPU utilization perspective but are there any official recommendations or benchmarks?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue of advantages/disadvantages. When you specify a runtime platform, you're targeting that platform specifically, whereas otherwise, you're targeting any possible platform. In the former case, the only necessary runtime components are brought in, while in the latter, there's just a loose reference to whatever runtime may be installed on the target. These packages will be employed either way. There's runtime packages for Windows, Linux, Mac, etc. Which ones are used obviously depends on where the app is ultimately deployed, or of course, the specification of a runtime flag.

Answer (score 0):

Packages like `System.Net.Sockets` contain the managed bits your applications depend on. So no matter what deployment approach you use (framework dependent or self contained), they are required, so restored by the build process.

Packages like `runtime.unix.System.Net.Sockets` usually contains only the native bits (shims to wrap on OS API). They are only required by self-contained deployment.

So simply speaking `System.Net.Sockets` depends on `runtime.unix.System.Net.Sockets` (if running on UNIX). They are not equivalent to each other as you assumed.

You don't need to call `dotnet restore --runtime linux-musl-x64`, as those runtime packages are useless during compilation. Restoration of such runtime packages can be deferred to `dotnet publish` when you target a specific runtime.